# How to insert varchar into postgresql json column

Tags: json, postgresql, triggers, sql-insert

I have been struggling in how to insert into a table in PG that has a JSON column...
I am extracting a bit column from another table, and now I want to insert that bit to the json column, for example:

```
INSERT INTO TABLE (JSON) VALUES( '{"IsAllowed":"' || is_allowed::TEXT || '"}'::JSON )
```

is_allowed represents to the bit from another table...
And I get:

```
"column "XXX" is of type json but expression is of type text"
```

Does anyone know how can I achieve this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be using `jsonb` instead of `json`, but that is not part of your question.

PostgreSQL does not allow bidirectional casting between `bit` and `boolean` types.  The same goes for `bit` and `int`.

Please try this:

```
insert into table (json) values
 (json_build_object('IsAllowed', is_allowed = 1::bit));
```

Answer (score 1):

Your command:

```
INSERT INTO TABLE (JSON) VALUES( '{"IsAllowed":"' || is_allowed::TEXT || '"}'::JSON )
```

is casting `'"}'` to JSON. Try adding some brackets:

```
INSERT INTO TABLE (JSON) VALUES( ('{"IsAllowed":"' || is_allowed::TEXT || '"}')::JSON )
```

*Note: I could not replicate the error you are receiving (got "Token ""}" is invalid.") but with the brackets this worked fine.*